# Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying' - Array swift json Error

Tags: arrays, json, string, swift

sorry in advance for my bad english.
I have a problem with my Swiftcode, i'm new in Swift so maybe you can help me :)

Here is my Code.

```
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if(error != nil)
        {
            println("error\(error)")
            return;
        }

        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json
        {
            var resultValue:String = parseJSON["message"] as String!;
            println("result: \(resultValue)")
            self.LabelFalscheEingabe.text = "\(resultValue)";

            if(resultValue == "Success")
            {
             var Projects:Array = parseJSON["projects"] as Array!; // here is the Error
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

'projects' is a variable from type Array on the server, so i want to get it as Array from the server, but if I try this i get the following error.

Error: "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'".

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your english looks fine to me, no need to apologise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your`Projects` array can't be declared like that, Swift has to know the *type* of the objects in the array.

If you don't know the type, then make it an array of `AnyObject`:

```
if let Projects = parseJSON["projects"] as? [AnyObject] {
    // do something with Projects
}
```

If you know it's an array of Strings, for example:

```
if let Projects = parseJSON["projects"] as? [String] {
    // do something with Projects
}
```

An array of Integers:

```
if let Projects = parseJSON["projects"] as? [Int] {
    // do something with Projects
}
```

An array of dictionaries made from JSON:

```
if let Projects = parseJSON["projects"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    // do something with Projects
}
```

Etc.